# How to serializable from java application and de-serializable on android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, deserialization, serializable

I'm a newbie from Android, and I'm developing an application on Android. The app need use a class to de-serializable and get data. This is class:

```
package fu.sna2014.smartnavigation.utility;

import java.io.Serializable;
    public class StreetObject implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 437865663147928104L;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private byte[] sound;
        public StreetObject(String id, String name, byte[] sound) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.sound = sound;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public byte[] getSound() {
            return sound;
        }

        public void setSound(byte[] sound) {
            this.sound = sound;
        }
    }
```

My problem is this class is serializabled from another Java application with package name:

```
package snaTool;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    /**
     *
     * @author conghits
     */
    public class StreetObject implements Serializable{
        /**
        * 
        */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 437865663147928104L;
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private byte[] sound;
        //private transient List<File> unInterestingLongLongList; 
        public StreetObject(String id, String name, byte[] sound) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.sound = sound;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public byte[] getSound() {
            return sound;
        }

        public void setSound(byte[] sound) {
            this.sound = sound;
        }   
    }
```

And when I de-serializable it make ClassNotFoundException snaTool.StreetObject. I have searched many topics and get a solution as make .jar for StreetObject from Java application and import to Andoird as libs but when I import, Eclipse( for coding Android) not found the .jar as libs, other word I can call class from the .jar on Eclipse. Anyone help me known what wrong here? Thanks so much and sorry about my English writing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated the problem yourself: the class has a different package name in your Android app.  Why are you doing that?  You should use exactly the same jar in both apps.

Comment: :)) Thanks for your answer, I fixed this problem easily, just create package "snaTool" in Eclipse and make class StreetObject into the package